# How to communicate between android and another process using broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a problem with registering a `broadcastReceiver` between my Activity and my Service which is defined in another process in my manifest.

I've tried some other tips like using `handlers` or `ContentProvider`
for communicating but it did't work as I expected, In fact I want to get the data continuously.

Here is my code in my Service:

```
Intent locationIntent = new Intent("LocationIntent");
        locationIntent.setAction("updatedLocations");
        locationIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MapBoxActivity.class);
        locationIntent.putExtra("list",updatedList);
        sendBroadcast(locationIntent);
```

and I register it in `OnCreate` of my Activity:

```
updatedLocationBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Timber.tag("localB").d("registered!");
                if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("updatedLocations")) {
                    sawLocationsList = (HashMap<Integer, MarkerItem>)intent.getSerializableExtra("list");
                    Timber.tag("sawL").d("updated" + sawLocationsList.toString());
                }
            }
        };
registerReceiver(updatedLocationBroadcast , new IntentFilter("updatedLocations"));
```

As I expected, I wanted to see my `broadcastReceiver` registers and my `Timber` logs `localB registered!` which is defined in my receiver but it doesn't work.

So, What's the best way to communicate between Activity and Service defined in another `process` and getting data continuously???

Note : my service gets data from server but the server is not realTime so I check the data by requesting periodically to server using `handlers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it doesn't work

That is because you over-specified your `Intent`. Replace:

```
    Intent locationIntent = new Intent("LocationIntent");
    locationIntent.setAction("updatedLocations");
    locationIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MapBoxActivity.class);
    locationIntent.putExtra("list",updatedList);
    sendBroadcast(locationIntent);
```

with:

```
    Intent locationIntent = new Intent("updatedLocations");
    locationIntent.putExtra("list",updatedList);
    sendBroadcast(locationIntent);
```

Note, though, that any app will be able to listen to this broadcast. Consider using `setPackage()` on the `Intent` to restrict the delivery to your own app.

> What's the best way to communicate between Activity and Service defined in another process and getting data continuously?

If I were forced into this process separation, I would consider a `Messenger`.

> my service gets data from server but the server is not realTime so I check the data by requesting periodically to server using handlers.

That hasn't been a recommended pattern in years. Please use `WorkManager`. Or, use `JobScheduler`, if you are not in position to adopt `WorkManager` (since it is part of AndroidX). In either of those approaches, you could get rid of the second process and greatly simplify your communications.

Comment: I've done it but didn't work, I also added ```intent.setPackage(getAppCtx.getPackageName)``` but my Timber does't log registration in activity as I expected. I also need my service to be ```Foreground``` and used ```JobScheduler``` for background processes...
but your Answer helped me understand the situation more...thanks a lot.